# Why did Cuphead delete my save files?

Tags: steam, cuphead

I loaded up the game offline, and it did not have my items and such. It still left me off where I was (zone 3) though nothing was completed. I Alt-F4'd the game to close it, afraid it would save and reset my progress, and then I turned it back on while being online. However, when I loaded the game back up, all three of my save slots were blank, with the only option being to start a new game. Is there a way to revert my progress? Or am I stuck being forced to replay the game.

Answer (score 1):

This is a save glitch. Your not the only one that has had this problem. Unfortunately, if you did not somehow back up your save in any way you have to restart.

Comment: Its just, that blunt? No way to fix it?

Comment: @ShadowZ. Afraid so. You probably glitched the game even further by launching it on offline mode since the save bug is related to disconnecting from steam. For future reference, copy your saves from %appdata%\Cuphead